# Are there any theorems giving a bound on the size of the type of an expression in the simply typed lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

If we consider the STLC, and assume that the cardinality of a type is the number of $\rightarrow$ in the type, assuming the traditional rules, suppose we have that $\Gamma \vdash e : t$. Is there any theorem giving us an upper bound on the cardinality of $t$?

Furthermore, we have some well-typed terms of the form $\lambda x : s . f$. Is there an upper bound on $s$?

I would expect the same upper bound can be used in both cases.

Comment: Presumably you mean this as parameterized by the size of $e$ or something(?) Obviously you can make (arbitrarily large) terms of the STLC with correspondingly large types, e.g. $\lambda x_1.\cdots\lambda x_n.t$ will have at least $n$ arrows in the type.

Comment: Yes, I mean parameterized by the size of  for example. If we take into account the size of the term, would that tell us anything about the size of the type annotations of $e$, or the type of $e$?

Comment: I think your question needs some clarification: if you are working with a Curry style representation of $\lambda$-terms, then  $\lambda x \cdot x$ can be assigned any type of the form $\tau \to \tau$ (and hence can be as big as you please); if you are working with a Church-style representation of $\lambda$-terms (in which type ascriptions are embedded in the terms), then the type of a term will be part of the term (and hence will be smaller than the size of the term).